# get text from int value in select case of sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I need convert int value in a select for string value for human Reading.

I try two forms but any works

```
select id, case Preparacion  when 1 then 'Yes' when 0 then 'No' else preparacion end as   Preparación
from pinchos 
inner join Laboratorios on Laboratorios.CodKais = Pinchos.codKais 
where entradaproduccion = '20140905'
```

And convert Preparacion  to varchar()

```
select id, case convert(varchar(1),Preparacion)  when '1' then 'Yes' when '0' then 'No' else preparacion end as Preparacion
from pinchos 
inner join Laboratorios on Laboratorios.CodKais = Pinchos.codKais 
where entradaproduccion = '20140905'
```

how I can show string value?

I only have read permisions in database and dont have Preparación table

Answer (score 0):

Compare as INT and cast when required.

Try this:
(untested code)

```
select  id, 
        case Preparacion 
            when 1 then 'Yes' 
            when 0 then 'No' 
            else CAST(preparacion as VARCHAR(255)) 
        end as Preparacion
from pinchos 
inner join Laboratorios on Laboratorios.CodKais = Pinchos.codKais 
where entradaproduccion = '20140905'
```

Answer (score -2):

You have forgottone an else there

select id, case Preparacion
when 1 then 'Yes' 
**else**
when 0 then 'No' else preparacion end
end as   Preparación
from pinchos 
inner join Laboratorios on Laboratorios.CodKais = Pinchos.codKais 
where entradaproduccion = '20140905'